# Помогите с задачей по циклам на python

Tags: python

Прохожу курс по Python и попалась задача:

> Нужно написать программу, которая будет считывать со стандартного
> ввода целочисленные границы промежутка (сначала левая, потом правая,
> каждая на отдельной строке). А дальше будет считывать целые числа со
> стандартного ввода пока не встретит пустую строку, которая будет
> означать конец ввода. Нужно будет проверить входят ли все введенные
> числа в промежуток, проверка включает в себя границы промежутка.

Я написал вот так:

```
g1 = input()
g2 = input()
g3 = input()
while g3 !="":
    g3 = input ()
if g1 <= g3 >= g2:
    print (True)
else:
    print (False)
```

Это последний вариант решения, перепробовал не одно, но всегда возвращает значение `false`.

Comment: Вы считываете строки и количество вводов у вас ограничено. Вам надо в список добавлять ввод(с конвертацией в число) до тех пор, пока не будет пустой ввод, а далее проверять список

Comment: g3 должно быть между g1 и g2, а не как тут написано: g1 <= g3 >= g2

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в том что вы читаете все числа, но не проверяете каждое на принадлежность интервалу.

```
low = int(input())      # нижняя граница
high = int(input())     # верхняя граница
between = True          # пока все числа в интервале

while line := input():  # вводить до первой пустой строки
    # обновить флаг если нужно
    if between:
        between = low <= int(line) <= high

print(between)
```

**P.S.** Это не правда что ваша программа всегда возвращает `False`. Если ввести три пустые строки, будет `True`, что логично.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
g3= []

g1 = int(input())
g2 = int(input())

while True:
    value = input()
    if value != "":
        g3.append(int(value))
    else:
        break

test = list(filter(lambda x: g1 <= x <= g2, g3))
print(test)
```

Тест:

```
50
150
49
89
65
170
0
31
51

[89, 65, 51]

[Program finished]
–———————-–———————-

40
150
40
50
170
150

[40, 50, 150]

[Program finished]
```

З.Ы. Вы сравнивали числа как строки, так как input() возвращает строку str. Что бы корректно сравнивать числа, сперва полученую строку нужно преобразовать, например через int() или float().

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем коде:

1. Ввод не конвертируется в числа из строки
2. Не запоминаются введенные числа, g3 всегда будет пустой строкой после выхода из цикла
3. Условие задано неверно, оно содержит взаимоисключающие условия и всегда будет False

Надо как-то так:

```
out = []
g1 = int(input())
g2 = int(input())
while (g3 := input()) != "":
    out.append(int(g3))

print(all([g1 <= i <= g2 for i in out]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Предложу такой вариант. Заводим булеву переменную `valid`, которая будет индикатором отсутствия недопустимых чисел, изначально задаем `True`. В каждой итерации цикла применяем логическое умножение `valid` на результат проверки очередного введенного числа `g1 <= int(g3) <= g2`. Если все числа подходящие, то `valid` будет сохранять значение `True`. Если же хоть одно число выйдет за границу диапазона, `valid` станет `False`.

```
valid, g1, g2 = True, int(input()), int(input())
while True:
    g3 = input()
    if g3 == '':
        break
    valid &= g1 <= int(g3) <= g2
print(valid)
```

```
45
100
46
88
79
99

True
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваша программа почти правильная. Я ее немножко изменил, чтобы она работала так, как вы хотите:

```
g1 = int(input())
g2 = int(input())
g3 = input()

while g3 != "":
    g3 = int(g3)
    if g1 <= g3 <= g2:
        print (True)
    else:
        print (False)
    g3 = input()
```

---

*Объяснение изменений:*

1. Функция `input()` всегда возвращает **строку**. Когда ожидается **целое число**, нужно строку перевести на него функцией `int()`.

   Для переменных `g1` и `g2` я это сделал сразу же — `int(input())`, но для переменной `g3`, в которой ожидается как целое число, так и (пустая) строка, я это сделал только после теста на пустую строку.
2. Я исправил **отступ** команды `if` (вместе со всеми ее частями) - она должна находится **внутри** цикла, чтобы цикл *не повторялся без тестирования (и обработки) текущего значения переменной `g3`.*
3. В условии команды `if` я исправил один **знак неравенства**.
4. Команду `g3 = input ()` **я переместил** на конец цикла, чтобы сначала проверить текущее значение переменной `g3`, и только после его обработки требовал от юзера новое значение.